# Disable Python basic optimization (-O)

Tags: python, debugging

On a given embedded Linux machine I have a Python 3.3 distribution installed which seems to have the optimization option `-O` enabled by default.
This has the following effects:

- `.pyo` files are being generated (rather than `.pyc`)
- `assert` statements have no effect
- `__debug__` is set to `False`
- Some IDEs seem to be unable to provide remote debugging (see [WingIDE](https://wingware.com/doc/debug/importing-the-debugger))

Is there a way to disable basic optimization on the command line? I tried to set `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` to empty string but this does not have any effect.

Comment: As a workaround, you can install your own python.

Comment: That's weird, because I could not find such an option in configure script for Python 3.3. Did you carefully inspect environment with `env` or `printenv`, and did you ensure that you are not using a wrapper that forces -O option?

Comment: I just found a patch which is being applied to the Python3.3.3 source in order to activate optimization by default. The distribution is based on Yocto and it comes with that patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python distribution I was using comes with Yocto and basic optimization is activated there by default (`Py_OptimizeFlag` is hard coded to `1` rather than `0`).

That version of Python also comes with an extra `-N` flag (which is not documented in the usual Python distributions).

So the answer to my question is to either set the `-N` command line option or to apply a patch to the Python sources which come with Yocto and recompile (as suggested by Karoly Horvath).